# Do pyspark need a local Spark installation?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-2.0

I'm trying to get going with spark. Trying to create a simple SQL connection to a database while running Spark in a docker container.

I do not have Spark installed on my laptop. Only inside my docker container.

I got the following code on my laptop:

```
spark = SparkSession \
.builder \
.master("spark://localhost:7077") \  # <-- Docker container with master and worker
.appName("sparktest") \
.getOrCreate()

jdbcDF = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
.option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver") \
.option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://xxx") \
.option("dbtable", "xxx") \
.option("user", "xxx") \
.option("password", "xxx").load()
```

I can't get it to work.
I either get `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver` or `ClassNotFoundException` from Java.
I've moved the files to the container and everything seems fine over there.

I've made sure the mssql jar files are on the SPARK_CLASSPATH on both driver and executor.

Am I supposed to have Spark installed locally for me to use PySpark against the remote master running in my docker container?

It looks like its trying to find the SQL driver on my laptop?

Everything is fine if i run code using spark-submit from inside the docker container.

I was trying to avoid going the route of jupyter hosted inside the docker container, but was hoping to not having to install Spark on my Windows laptop and keeping it in my linux container.

Comment: This is expected behavior. With `spark-submit`, application gets full fledged spark environment composed from various sources of configurations. The code you have actually starts a driver on your host machine which lacks all the configurations along with JDBC driver. Hence the error. Have you tried adding `SQLServerDriver` to sbt dependencies?

Comment: @D3V I don't understand it. Why would i need the database connector on my laptop. I don't wan't to read data into my laptop, it needs to go to the container which in  production runs on a high RAM server. I've only worked with Sparklyr before and there data would be read by the cluster from the database, not pass through my own workstation until i collected it from Spark into R.

Comment: It depends on where your driver machine is, running job from local machine makes it a driver machine. It essentially means, JDBC driver is needed on local. It doesn't need complete spark installation. However required jars need to be on driver classpath which happens to be your laptop. On a side note, if you are experimenting then you are way better off with notebooks like zeppelin or jupyter than this approach.

Comment: Hmm ok, i think i've missunderstood the purpose of pyspark then. Its just the Spark API in a python wrapper. its not a python Spark client that you can use to remotely interact with Spark.

Comment: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-architecture.html refer to this, you will get some hang of it.

Comment: You can definitely remotely interact and it is one of the reasons why it is so popular. but right now a part of application (driver) is running on your laptop which makes it look like it can't.

Comment: @D3V Thank you! Got it working using SparkSession.config setting the `spark.jars` pointing it to the jar on my local machine.I'm still slightly confused if this means reading data will go through the driver or actually be read from the executors on the cluster.

Comment: The data will be read on remote machines, you don't have to worry about it. It is just that spark needs JDBC jars in order to instruct executors about execution plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced it before and for a solution you can download jdbc driver and set the driver configuration manually with giving jdbc driver path

```
from pyspark.context import SparkConf
conf = SparkConf()
conf.set('spark.jars', '/PATH_OF_DRIVER/driver.jar')    
conf.set('spark.executor.extraClassPath', '/PATH_OF_DRIVER/driver.jar')
```

Comment: Thank you Ali this is what i did and it worked without installing Spark.